# Where can I find the released combustion energy in NASA CEA rocket problem?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, energy, combustion

I am using NASA CEA program for a study project.
I have read the CEA Nasa user's manual over and over, yet I haven't found an answer to my question which is :

**where can I found in the output of NASA CEA the energy released during a combustion in a rocket problem ?**

For instance, using CEA I have simulated the following problem :

- Rocket problem with infinite area-combustor and assuming equilibrium in the combustion chamber
- pressure chamber at 1 bar
- combustion of H2 with O2

And in the output I have these data, but I am not sure where or how I can find the energy released by the combustion of H2 and O2 : **Is it the yellow-highlighted one ? Or is it the red-circled one ? Or it's not given, I have to calculate using the output data ?**

Thank you

[image: output data]

Comment: A little *subtraction* should do the trick.

Comment: Do you mean subtracting Hthroat - Hchamber = - 1293.48 - 6.6529 ?  I thought that formation enthalpies should be involved somehow